# OctoberCMS translate plugin with SEO plugin doesnt translate SEO keywords for CMS pages and Blogs

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I am using OctoberCMS SEO translation plugin https://octobercms.com/plugin/anandpatel-seoextension and it works as per my expectations .. but I have a query with Translate plugin https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-translate . Please see my couple of screenshots first.

[image]

[image]

As you can see in my above 2 screenshots, In blog pages while I am supposed to create or edit a blog, I am unable to make translation for Meta Title, Meta Description , Meta Keywords etc ..

Additionally, In my CMS pages also, I am unable to make my "Meta Keywords" translatable ..

I have tried to put below code in one of my active plugin's `Plugin.php` file to be able to make my Blog "Meta Title" field translatable, but it didnt work either ..

```
\RainLab\Blog\Models\Post::extend(function($model) {            
            $model->translatable[] = 'seo_title';
        });
```

And tried below code as well ..

```
\AnandPatel\SeoExtension\Models\BlogPost::extend(function($model) {
            $model->translatable[] = 'seo_title';
        });
```

Can someone guide me how can I make these fields translatable ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I debugged It and The problem is

> `SEO Extension Plugin` is listening for `\Event::listen('backend.form.extendFields' ...`  and this event is fired after `backend.form.extendFieldsBefore` so new added fields are not translatable.

`backend.form.extendFieldsBefore` this event is responsible to convert field in to `translatable` field so fields which are added after this event are not shown as `translatable`.

**I am planning to correct this behavior** and PR contribution to author repo https://github.com/anand-patel/oc-seo-extension once i get some free time

> Solution could be [ need to be done in plugin base code ] to use `backend.form.extendFieldsBefore` event in `SEO Extension Plugin` and during extension of fields it need to directly work with `raw config`, right now it uses `$widget->addFields` so it has to remove that and directly injecting fields to `config` so, later on newly added  fields can be processed by `RainLab.Translate Plugin` using `backend.form.extendFieldsBefore` event.

**So For now workaround**  in your custom plugin add fields which are already have support for transnational or you can again use `extendFieldsBefore` and work with `raw config` to add fields.

**here we just use easy solution and add override field with translatable field type**

```php
use RainLab\Blog\Models\Post;
use Event;
use System\Classes\PluginManager;

public function register() {

  Post::extend(function($post) {
      if (!$post->propertyExists('translatable')) {
          $post->addDynamicProperty('translatable', []);
      }
      $post->translatable = array_merge($post->translatable, ['seo_title', 'seo_description' /* so on ....*/]);
  });

  Event::listen('backend.form.extendFields', function($widget) {
      if(PluginManager::instance()->hasPlugin('RainLab.Blog') && $widget->model instanceof \RainLab\Blog\Models\Post)
        {
            $widget->addFields([
              'seo_title' => [
                  'label'   => 'Meta Title',
                  'type'    => 'mltext', //<- HERE
                  'tab'     => 'SEO'
              ],
              'seo_description' => [
                  'label'   => 'Meta Description',
                  'type'    => 'mltextarea', //<- HERE
                  'size'    => 'tiny',
                  'tab'     => 'SEO'
              ],
              'seo_keywords' => [
                  'label'   => 'Meta Keywords',
                  'type'    => 'mltextarea', //<- HERE
                  'size'    => 'tiny',
                  'tab'     => 'SEO'
              ],
              'canonical_url' => [
                  'label'   => 'Canonical URL',
                  'type'    => 'mltext', //<- HERE
                  'tab'     => 'SEO',
                  'span'    => 'left'
              ],
              'redirect_url' => [
                  'label'   => 'Redirect URL',
                  'type'    => 'mltext', //<- HERE
                  'tab'     => 'SEO',
                  'span'    => 'right'

              ],
              // ... so on
          ],
          'secondary');
        }
  });
}
```

but this is workaround for standard solution, I am planning to correct this and push PR to author plugin repo may be -> https://github.com/anand-patel/oc-seo-extension

if any doubts please comment.